# SoapUI request with SSL certificate (Error getting response; javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?)

Tags: ssl, spring-security, https, soapui, java-17

I have a project on **Java+Spring**. And there is a sertificate storage (**.jks** file). I set up this .jks file in my project. Now I want to make a request with the **SoapUI 5.5.0** using SSL.

I opened SoapUI -> File -> New Rest Project -> insert url (https://localhost:8080/my-endpoint-01) and click OK
-> then gave to soapUI-project new name "Spring Security"

Then I went to configure the **SSL** certificate: File -> Preferences -> SSL Settings:

- Keystore: *path to the storage of the keys .jks*
- Keystore Password: *password*

[image]

Also in the working area of the SoapUI, at the bottom left there is a section "Request Properties". There is a "SSL Keystore" item here. I also selected my certificate store here:

[image]

Then I want to test with https request:

https://localhost:8080/my-endpoint-01

but I got an error: "**Error getting response; javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?**":

[image]

**Can you explain to me, please, what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: 8080 is  generally a plaintext port, not an HTTPS port. Try 8443 or whatever your Tomcat is set up for with HTTPS.